# MySql isValid method for timeout

Tags: mysql, jdbc

Can I use the `isValid(0)` function to check whether the connection is still active (alive)?

I am getting following exception :

> **com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:**
>
> The last packet successfully received from the server was  milliseconds ago.
>   The last packet sent successfully to the server was  milliseconds ago, which  is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'.
>
> You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem

I can't increase the 'wait_timeout' value.

Also I tried with `autoReconnect=true` but I need to handle the exception anyway.

I got to know about the `isValid()` function.
But I couldn't understand what kind of validity it checks.

Would using `isValid(0)` help me solve timeout problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html), `isValid` is required to run "a query", so it should be useful.

> The driver shall submit a query on the connection or use some other mechanism that positively verifies the connection is still valid when this method is called.

Seems like something your connection pool should be doing for you...